# XML data binding in C++ with simple \ non intrusive data model

Tags: c++, xml

I'm evaluating looking for an XML binding tool for C++.

I'm interested in a tool that uses separate data model and parser. that is:

- a "simple" class that only holds the data from the XML, without having the parsing logic. preferably a class without external dependencies - just using simple types, structs, and arrays.
- a separate class that handles the parsing.

This is somewhat similar to what happens with the XSD tool for .net.

Answer (score 0):

I have regularly used the [XSD library from CodeSynthesis](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/).  This has a very simple getter interface code generated from the specification.  I specifically use it for the SAX binding, which optimises access and use parse-time, for fastest XML processing.  You can use the SAX tool and dispatch to your own handler, or the DOM tool object-maps the XML directly, revealing simple accessor functions.

Comment: This is what I started using. But I prefer something where to final data classes are cleaner, and don't depend on the parsing infrastructure. (like in XSD\Tree). on the other hand, I don't want to handcraft the data model (like in XSD\Parser)